# List comprehensions in Jinja

Tags: python, jinja2

I have two lists:

1. strainInfo, which contains a dictionary element called 'replicateID'
2. selectedStrainInfo, which contains a dictionary element called 'replicateID'

I'm looking to check if the replicateID of each of my strains is in a list of selected strains, in python it would be something like this:

```
for strain in strainInfo:
    if strain.replicateID in [selectedStrain.replicateID for selectedStrain in selectedStrainInfo]
        print('This strain is selected')
```

I'm getting the correct functionality in django, but I'm wondering if there's a way to simplify using a list comprehension:

```
{% for row in strainInfo %}
    {% for selectedStrain in selectedStrainsInfo %}
       {% if row.replicateID == selectedStrain.replicateID %} 
           checked 
       {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 21):

Since v2.7 there is `selectattr`:

> Filters a sequence of objects by applying a test to the specified attribute of each object, and only selecting the objects with the test succeeding.
>
> If no test is specified, the attribute’s value will be evaluated as a boolean.
>
> Example usage:
>
> ```
> {{ users|selectattr("is_active") }}
> {{ users|selectattr("email", "none") }}
> ```
>
> Similar to a generator comprehension such as:
>
> ```
> (u for user in users if user.is_active)
> (u for user in users if test_none(user.email))
> ```

See [docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#selectattr).

Answer (score 20):

[List comprehensions are not supported in Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/faq/#isn-t-it-a-terrible-idea-to-put-logic-into-templates)

You could pass the data, via Jinja, to JavaScript variables like so

```
var strainInfo = {{strainInfo|safe}};
var selectedStrainInfo = {{selectedStrainInfo|safe}};
```

and then do your clean up there.

Use Jinja's `safe` filter to prevent your data from being HTML-escaped.