# Jinja2 getting syntax error Python generator

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

Below is my code. I'm getting a syntax error but in Python there is no such issue

```
{% for stud in  [dict(item.split("=") for item in item.split(",")) for item in item.split(";")] %}
  print {"hi"}
{% endfor %}
```

Exception:

```
Syntax error in jinja2 template: expected token ',', got 'for'
```

Sample Input:

```
studId=ValueA,studName=valueB;studId=ValueC,studName=ValueD
```

Sample code used in Python:

```py
item = "studId=ValueA,studName=valueB;studId=ValueC,studName=ValueD"


for stud in [dict(item.split("=") for item in item.split(",")) for item in item.split(";")]:
  print(stud['studName'])
```

Sample output:

```
valueB
ValueD
```

Comment: jinja isn't python, you can't expect to use python code within it

Comment: *It would be helpful if you can provide sample input and desired output*. For example, `item = 'key1=val1;key2=val2'` seems to be a sample input in this case.

Comment: noted. can you please kindly advice how it can be done. I am new to it

Comment: @rv.kvetch, I have updated my question with sample input, sample output and sample code in python

Answer (score 0):

At least from what I noticed, jinja doesn't seem to [support list comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328023/list-comprehensions-in-jinja).

A workaround I've tested with is to [pass in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036082/call-a-python-function-from-jinja2) which performs a list comprehension to Jinja2, which can then be used to render the template:

```
import jinja2


item = "studId=ValueA,studName=valueB;studId=ValueC,studName=ValueD"


def get_values(values):
    return [dict(v.split("=") for v in v.split(",")) for v in values.split(";")]


ts = """\
{% for value in get_values(values) -%}
  {{ value.studName }}
{% endfor %}\
"""

fields = {'get_values': get_values, 'values': item}

rendered = jinja2.Template(ts).render(**fields)
```

Output:

```
>>> rendered
'valueB\nValueD\n'
```

Comment: so there is no other options

Comment: well, you could look around and maybe try Googling for a workaround. I know it could work if you convert your list comprehension to a nested `for` loop, though.

Comment: can i know my jinja2 template how to call your code ya. i need pass value from jinja2 to your python

Comment: @josh I didn't really understand that

Comment: Let me explain how it work. in my Ansible variable i will pass studIdf and studName to jinja2 template. If i want jinja2 call python script for every loop is it possible? python like a function return the value

Comment: @josh I see, that definitely helps clarify the use case. I updated the answer above with info on how you can pass a Python function in to jinja2 when rendering the template.

Comment: cool. can i know this python code should it be in j2 or should place in separate file.  besides this ts =  referring to what ya. can share me some details how it will call the method get_values. should i put in same file or different file so that i know where to start n start research in calling the function get_values

Comment: Hmm, the python code should be in a separate python module ideally, since I suppose Jinja might not understand list comprehensions. The `ts` is the template string that you pass in to Jinja. When `render` is called, Jinja will then perform string interpolation (roughly) and evaluate the template string, after replacing template variables in the `fields` mapping that you define.

Comment: jinja is quite funny, why didn't it just use python syntax?